# Drawing Knots in SVG

Tags: svg

I'm trying to render a simple knot in SVG using paths, although I'm not committed to using paths over any other SVG element.  The difficulty I'm having is in showing the overlap of the knot, as SVG elements tend to intersect instead.

I've included below two failed attempts, the first illustrating the intersection problem, and the second overcoming it but with the new problem of the line not appearing continuous (there are now overlaps at the corners).

How can I proceed so that the rendered image appears as if it were a continous strand, and so that overlapping/intersecting sections clearly depict which part is on top and which is below.

[image: This illustrates the intersection problem]
[image]

Edit:

The first example is simply a closed path with a second closed path of slightly larger stroke-width behind it.  The second example is the same pattern, but composed of several paths.

Comment: Are you using software(like Illustrator or Inkscape) or are you just creating the paths manually?  If it's the former, I might be able to create an answer of how I would approach the problem using Inkscape.  In short, I'd keep the original path just to have a blue line, then create a layer(or more paths) on top of it to illustrate the correct outline.  Also, this might belong in graphicdesign.stackexchange.com if this ends up being a stylistic question and not a technical one.

Comment: No, I would be creating these elements programmatically, not with illustrator or Inkscape.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two main approaches to achieving knots (that I've used anyway):

1. Use multiple paths and hide the joins behind other lines
2. Use overlay segments to redraw the crossing points

Most of the time, you'll probably have to use technique (2).  And that's the approach I am using below to reproduce your knot:

```html
<svg width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 100 100">

    <polygon points="20,80 60,15 45,20 70,90"
             fill="none" stroke="#666" stroke-width="6" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
    <polygon points="20,80 60,15 45,20 70,90"
             fill="none" stroke="#69c" stroke-width="3" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
    
    <!-- overlay segment -->
    <polyline points="45,20 70,90"
          fill="none" stroke="#666" stroke-width="6" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
    <polyline points="60,15 45,20 70,90 20,80"
          fill="none" stroke="#69c" stroke-width="3" stroke-linejoin="round"/>

</svg>
```

If I recolour the overlay, you can see how I've done it:

```html
<svg width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 100 100">

    <polygon points="20,80 60,15 45,20 70,90"
             fill="none" stroke="#666" stroke-width="6" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
    <polygon points="20,80 60,15 45,20 70,90"
             fill="none" stroke="#69c" stroke-width="3" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
    
    <!-- overlay segment -->
    <polyline points="45,20 70,90"
          fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="6" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
    <polyline points="60,15 45,20 70,90 20,80"
          fill="none" stroke="green" stroke-width="3" stroke-linejoin="round"/>

</svg>
```

The green overlay line extends further than the red one to cover the fact that the red one extends the entire length of that line segment.  The two corners at the end of the red line needed to be redrawn.

I did it this way so I could just re-use the existing path points without having to worry about calculating the coordinates of a shorter segment of the line.  But sometimes, if you have a more complex path, you may be forced to do that.  Here's an example of what this would look like:

```html
<svg width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 100 100">

    <polygon points="20,80 60,15 45,20 70,90"
             fill="none" stroke="#666" stroke-width="6" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
    <polygon points="20,80 60,15 45,20 70,90"
             fill="none" stroke="#69c" stroke-width="3" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
    
    <!-- overlay segment -->
    <polyline points="46.79,25 53.93,45"
          fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="6" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
    <polyline points="46.79,25 53.93,45"
          fill="none" stroke="green" stroke-width="3" stroke-linejoin="round"/>

</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed response!